# how to dispatch custom event in flex 

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flexbuilder

how to dispatch custom event in flex

in my main mxml file i have put this code to dispatch this function

```
private var ageVerifyMessage:AgeVerify = new AgeVerify();

public function onAgeVerifyFailed(event:ControlManagerEvent) : void
    {
        ageVerifyMessage.visible = true;
        return;
    }// end function
```

in controlmanagerevent i have used this code

```
private function getUserDetailsHandler(event:ResultEvent) : void
    {
        userDetails = ResponseParser.parseUserDetails(event.result as Object);
        if (!userDetails || !userDetails.age)
        {
            if (_flashVars.birth_date && _flashVars.birth_date != "" && _flashVars.birth_date.toString().split("/").length == 3)
            {
                reportConnectedUser();
            }
            else
            {
                dispatchEvent(new ControlManagerEvent(ControlManagerEvent.onAgeVerifyFailed));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            reportConnectedUser(userDetails.age);
        }
        return;
    }// end function



private var _controller:IControlManager;


public function initApp() : void
    {
        _controller.addEventListener(ControlManagerEvent.onServerStatusChange, onServerStatusChange);
        _controller.addEventListener(ControlManagerEvent.onSelfCamFailed, onSelfCamFailed);
        _controller.addEventListener(ControlManagerEvent.onNoCamerasFound, onNoCamerasFound);
        _controller.addEventListener(ControlManagerEvent.onAgeVerifyFailed, onAgeVerifyFailed);

_controller.initController();
        return;
    }// end function




<local:AgeVerify horizontalCenter="0" id="ageVerifyMessage1" verticalCenter="0" visible="false"/>
```

i want to ask what i am missing why my customevents not working

Answer (score 1):

From your code I can see you're listening events of `_controller` but the object which dispatches event isn't `_controller` but `this`.

Comment: @ constantiner i have used it like                               public function initApp() : void
  {                                                         _controller.addEventListener(ControlManagerEvent.onAgeVerifyFailed, onAgeVerifyFailed);                                                      where private var _controller=Icontrolmanager

Comment: @ Constantiner that means i should edit code like                       this.addEventListener(ControlManagerEvent.onAgeVerifyFailed, onAgeVerifyFailed);

Comment: @ Constantiner it didnt work,in my code i have use this code to display ageverify(ageverify is my custom component) where i have used id ageverifymessage1 as yoou told me to rename id name this is code     <local:AgeVerify horizontalCenter="0" id="ageVerifyMessage1" verticalCenter="0" visible="false"/>
 do you think id name should be ageVerifyMessage instead of ageVerifyMessage1 if your answer is yes i must tell you if i do that i get error saying 'conflict exist with defination ageVerifyMessage in namespace internal'

Comment: It is very hard to read this kind of unformated code. Please add this code to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems `_controller.dispatchEvent(YourEvent)` should work.

Or, I assume you're not using any event framework like Parsley or Swiz, your _controller should be kind of root in the component tree:

```
Application
    IControlManager(_controller)
        HBox
            YourComponent
```

When you dispatch an bubbling event in YourComponent, your _controller will be possible to invoke corresponding listeners.

Comment: `Event(type:String, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false)`, set `bubbles` to `true`.